# Finding limit of hyperpolic expression.

Tags: limits, hyperbolic-functions

I am having trouble of how to solve this kind of problem. I have to show the limit of the function:

$f(x)=\frac{1 - \tanh x}{e^{-2x}}$

$\lim_{x\to\infty} f(x)$

I am to do this without using differential calculus. How do i go about doing this?

EDIT:

$\tanh x = \frac{e^x - e^{-x}}{e^x + e^{-x}}$

Comment: you can firstly use Taylor series, but do remember to expand enough terms (with power of higher order). And do you know the exact expression of $tanh x$?

Comment: Added an edit, but i don't get what you mean.

Comment: simplify the expression of f(x) first. And you mean you don't know how to use Taylor series to expand the numerator and denominator? The aim is to find the infinite quantity of equivalent order.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use that $$\tanh(x)=\frac{e^x-e^{-x}}{e^x+e^{-x}}$$ and we get $$\frac{1-\tanh(x)}{e^{-2x}}=\frac{2e^{-x}}{e^{-2x}(e^x+e^{-x})}=\frac{2e^{x}}{e^x+e^{-x}}=\frac{2}{1+e^{-2x}}$$

Comment: Yes i know that, that is the value of tanh(x) but i don't get how I show what the limit is.

Comment: This is really great, but could you add additional calculation steps? I am a bit unsure how exactly you go from step to step.